# Error 13 when executing mysqldump to export a database into a cvs file

Tags: mysql, linux, selinux

I would like to export my database into a .csv file but I got a problem when I execute the command to do that:

```
   mysqldump -u root -p -t  -T~/tesht/ database orders --fields-terminated-by=',' 
    mysqldump: Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file '/home/motocol/tesht/orders.txt' (Errcode: 13)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

Doing some research about the problem I found this:

> It is important to note that the directory you specify must be
>   writeable by the user the MySQL server runs as. If it is not, you'll
>   get an error like this:
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 1: Can't create/write to file
>   '/path/to/filename.txt' (Errcode: 13) when executing 'SELECT INTO
>   OUTFILE' If your Linux machine has SELinux enabled, then the directory
>   must also be allowed by the SELinux configuration for MySQL to write
>   to.

Which is exactly what I get as an error, however I already thought I did that following the instruction on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474222/mariadb-10-centos-7-moving-datadir-woes) by running:

Ensure the user:group is mysql:mysql
Set the SELinux tag to mysqld_db_t
Set the SELinux user to system_u

and now when I do ls -Z I get:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mysql   mysql      6 Nov 16 16:21 tesht
```

but I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the directory above is writable by mysql user? Have you tried using `/tmp` and then relocating the file afterwards?

Comment: This question may be better suited to serverfault.com, which focuses on  professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration.

Comment: @miken32 when I do that I don't get a file.txt I just get a normal dump file file.sql

Comment: It creates both `orders.txt` and `orders.sql` when run with the `-T` option.

Comment: @miken32 I only see orders.sql there's no orders.txt and the weird part is if I run the command again it says that orders.txt is already there.